# catkin_create_pkg or roscreate-pkg?

Tags: ros, catkin, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I need to modify hector_slam for my situation. So i learned that i need to create/build a new package.

So i want to create just like existing hector_slam package and modify it like i want.

For creating new hector_slam package to modify, which one is suitable and easier for my situation. catkin package (http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingPackage)  or ros package (http://wiki.ros.org/roscreate) ?

Thanks,

Basak

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234311/catkin_create_pkg-or-roscreate-pkg?/) by [bsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/26601/bsk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2016-05-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`roscreate` is a remnant from the old `rosbuild` build system. For any new projects you should be using the `catkin` build system and correspondingly, `catkin_create_pkg`.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2016-05-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2